# Linear Feedback Shift Register efficiency

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, shift-register

I have the following code implement a shift action of a linear feedback shift register:

```
public int DoShift()
{
    //Find new top bit
    int feedback = Contents & tapSequence;
    int newBit = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    {
        newBit = 1 & (newBit ^ feedback);
        feedback >>= 1;
    }
    //Remember falloff, shift register, add new bit
    int result = Contents & 1;
    Contents >>= 1;
    Contents += newBit << (length - 1);
    return result;
}
```

where

- Contents is the current contents of the register
- tapSequence is the XOR tap sequence, where a 1 represents a tapped bit and a 0 represents an untapped bit.
- length is the number of bits the register has.

However, having run a CPU usage test, this function takes up as much as 60% of my runtime (for what I thought would've been a fairly lightweight method). Is there a more efficient way to write this?
Is there a way to XOR the contents of an int with its own bits (so as to do away with the for loop)?

Comment: Do you really need signed numbers? Maybe the sign extension on the right shift is causing more hits than expected? Did you do a release compile? Running it out of the debugger? Can you break out of the `for` loop early? Change it to a `while` loop somehow?

Comment: `newBit` is basically the parity of `feedback`. Take a look [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityLookupTable) to find some alternatives to the loop. Btw, the last `Contents += ` can be expressed as a bitwise OR because `newBit` is just one bit.

Comment: Signal numbers? I assume you refer to the tap sequence...can't think of a better implementation for it. No release compile, just running it with the VS debug tools. I suppose it could be broken once `feedback == 0`, I'll add that. Why would changing to a while loop help?

Comment: Hadn't thought of it like parity, thanks for the link, will have a dig. Would `Contents = Contents ^ (newBit << (length - 1))` be more efficient then?

Comment: It might. But you would have to measure for a definite answer. Btw, I would arrange the bits in the opposite direction (so coefficients of lower exponents correspond to less significant bits). But that's just a question of taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have gone with the following solution:

```
public int DoShift()
{
    //Remember falloff, shift register, add new bit
    int result = Contents & 1;
    Contents = (Contents >> 1) ^ 
        ((CountBits(Contents & tapSequence) % 2) << (length - 1));
    return result;
}

//Brian Kernighan method of counting bits
public static int CountBits(int value)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (value != 0)
    {
        count++;
        value &= value - 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Additionally, I may also attempt some to run elements of the broader programme in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public int DoShift()
{
    int newBit = 1 << (length - 1); // you can save it as class member
    int result = Contents & 1;
    int feedback = Contents & tapSequence;
    Contents >>= 1;
    while(feedback != 0) {
      feedback &= feedback - 1;
      Contents ^= newBit;
    }
    return result;
}
```

In addition, exist more efficient approach, named "reversed LSFR". It's idea - apply tapSequence to whole register just once, if result is 1.

See example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register